# How to add a new array field to collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example, I have a collection, such as `User`, with one field `name` (and default `_id` field). I insert some documents to this collection.

Then I want to add a field `emails` (which is an array to insert multiple emails) to this collection. If it is a normal field (not is an array), it can do easy with `update` and $set. But, with the array, I cannot create a new field with `update` command and $upsert, $addToSet, $push... because the array has not created before.

I think this is a common behavior, but I cannot find any way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the `$set`, `$addToSet`, and `$push` operators will create the array if the field doesn't exist yet.  Make sure you've added `email` to your Mongoose model's schema for the `update` to properly occur.

```js
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    emails: [String]
});
```

All three of the below options would have the same effect of adding the array of emails if the `emails` field doesn't exist yet or is empty:

```js
var emails = ['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'];
User.update({_id: id}, {$set: {emails: emails}}, function(err, num) {...});
User.update({_id: id}, {$addToSet: {emails: {$each: emails}}}, function(err, num) {...});
User.update({_id: id}, {$push: {emails: {$each: emails}}}, function(err, num) {...});
```

Comment: Thank, you save me. My mistake is I use $addToSet, but I push a single item to array, and it don't allow. Then I create an array and use $ set. Hooray, it work properly.

Answer (score -2):

```
db.t1.insert({name:"sachin"})
db.t1.insert({name:"shukla"})
db.t1.update({}, {$set:{arr:[]}}, {multi:true} )
db.t1.update({}, {$push: {arr:"tmp"} }, {multi:true} )
```

[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/079e100pjbwwjo1/Screenshot%202015-06-21%2021.16.38.png?dl=0)